# Protect Post Permalink From Copy

Tags: permalinks, encryption

It is possible to protect my post permalinks to get copy from other users or bots ? 
Let's say the post permalinks that tagged with tag "A" to get encrypted and all post to show in browser with:

Post title (1)permalink => mysite.com/A

Post title (2)permalink =>    mysite.com/A

Post title (3)permalink => mysite.com/A

Post title (4)permalink => mysite.com/A

Post title (5)permalink => mysite.com/A

Post title (6)permalink => mysite.com/A

If this can set by browser cookie Set-Cookie: get_postID ID=456755; domain=mysite.com; path=/; !!!!

Or any other way that can hide and encrypt post permalinks.

Thank you!
Gregory

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't practically possible.

URLs are important part of whole HTTP protocol thing, web is built upon. Browser needs to make a request for a specific URL, which WordPress needs to process and return content.

There is no practical way to set up this process. You could obscure it some browser–side, but it's nothing techie person won't defeat in seconds.